# Right Arrow meanings in Scala

Tags: scala

In Chapter 9 of Programming In Scala, there is an example method like this:

```
def twice(op: Double => Double, x: Double) = op(op(x))
```

The author said in the book:

> The type of op in this example is
> Double => Double, which means it is a
> function that takes one Double as an
> argument and returns another Double.

I don't understand what is "Double => Double" here, in previous chapters, where "=>" appears only means function literal, and never wrote like this "Type => Type", because according to Scala function literal syntax definition, the right part of function literal is the function body, how can a function body be "Double" ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Because it has two usages.

First, you could use => to define function literal.

```
scala> val fun = (x: Double) => x * 2
fun: (Double) => Double = <function1>

scala> fun (2.5)
res0: Double = 5.0
```

It's pretty easy. But the question here is, what type `fun` is? It is a "function that takes a Double as an argument and return a double", right?

So how could I annotate fun with its type? That is `(Double) => (Double)`. Well, the previous example could be rewritten to:

```
scala> val fun: Double => Double = (x: Double) => x * 2
fun: (Double) => Double = <function1>

scala> fun (2.5)                                       
res1: Double = 5.0
```

OK, then what does the following code do?

```
def twice(op: Double => Double, x: Double) = op(op(x))
```

Well, it tells you that op is a `(Double => Double)`, which means it needs a function which takes a Double and return a Double.

So you could pass the previous `fun` function to its first argument.

```
scala> def twice(op: Double => Double, x: Double) = op(op(x))    
twice: (op: (Double) => Double,x: Double)Double

scala> twice (fun, 10)
res2: Double = 40.0
```

And it will be equivalent to replacing `op` with `fun`, and replace `x` with `10`, that is `fun(fun(10))` and the result will be 40.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to separating the parameter list from the function body in a function literal, the double arrow can be used as syntactic sugar for a FunctionN type:

`T => R` means `Function1[T, R]`

`(T1, T2) => R` means `Function2[T1, T2, R]`

...

In your example, this means that `op` is a function that takes a Double and returns a Double (as the author explained).

As another example, it's possible to write

```
// declare len as a function that takes a String and returns an Int,
// and define it as returning the length of its argument
val len: String => Int = { _.length }

// or, a more verbose version that uses '=>' in both ways
val len: String => Int = { (s: String) => s.length }

len("apple") // returns 5
```

Comment: Why are you enumerating `Function`? (as in `FunctionN`, `Function1`, etc)

Comment: @jcora - FunctionN is a trait in Scala, Function1 is a type of that trait that represents a function with 1 argument - check out https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/functional-scala-functions-as-objects-as-functions/ and http://mikefroh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/intro-to-functional-programming-with.html

Answer (score 2):

That is a function that takes a double and returns a double.

```
scala> def  d2d = (d:Double) => d 
d2d: (Double) => Double
```

It's type is `Function1[Double,Double]`