# Scala extends double arrow

Tags: scala, syntax, traits

I was looking at the [Anorm source code and for the `RowParser` trait](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala) it has the declaration:

```
trait RowParser[+A] extends (Row => SqlResult[A]) { ... }
```

I was curious what type `(Row => SqlResult[A])` is? I haven't been able to find an explanation of the syntax anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right Arrow meanings in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878347/right-arrow-meanings-in-scala)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is syntactic sugar for `Function1` which is the same as this:

```
trait RowParser[+A] extends Function1[Row, SqlResult[A]]
```

If you look further in the [Anorm source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala#L88) you'll see that when the trait is implemented it has to define an `apply` function since it's implementing the Function1 trait.